# Function space vs Operator space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I was always under the impression that operators refer to functions that map functions to functions, whereas the term function is more general.

However, in [these notes by Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/21/245b-notes-11-the-strong-and-weak-topologies/) he first discusses the weak/weak-* topology defined on a vector space. He then says "now we turn our attention from function spaces to spaces of operators" when discussing the strong and weak operator topologies (the space of bounded linear transformations between two normed vector spaces).

What exactly is the distinction here a function space and an operator space? Is a mapping between vector spaces considered an operator whereas mapping the vector space to the underlying scalar field merely a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just terminology. Technically, operators $T:U \rightarrow V$ between vector spaces are functions, too, because for every $u \in U$ there is exactly one $v \in V$ such that $T(u) = v$.

But yes, it is common that $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued functions are only considered functions.

Usually, operators are linear. They have the nice property that they are continuous, iff $T$ is bounded on the unit sphere. Those operators are the most important subjects of functional analysis. It is common that $U$ is in fact a function space, like $C([0, 1])$ and this is where the difference in terminology arises: You deal with operators (that, as discussed, are functions, too) that map functions on functions,. So the word operator is just used to make clear that we have entered a higher level of abstraction.